# Creating folders from mySql ids and inserting data in them

Tags: mysql, directory

I have a very large table of records (about 30,000), which include an id as the primary key. I need to create a folder for each record, and put an image (image url is saved inside the table) inside each folder. Any ideas how this could be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT id, url FROM yourtable";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    mkdir("/path/to/location/{$row['id']}");
    file_put_contents(file_get_contents($url), "/path/to/location/{$row['id']}/image.jpg");
}
```

connecting to the db, picking out appropriate filenames, and most DEFINITELY adding some error handling, etc... is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Use your favorite scripting language and just loop through the records, creating the directory and downloading the image. It shouldn't be more than a few lines of code in most scripting languages.

Comment: Maybe he does not have no such thing as a 'favorite scripting language' ;)

Comment: Laurent, then (s)he can pick one. It shouldn't take too much time learning the basics of one, and it's certainly useful skills for someone doing this kind of work so the time is well spent.

Comment: @laurent - s(he) also is unlikely to have 'no' favorite or desired language given he/she is clearly needing to create folders for some purpose of image storage and probable web display given they state URL. Ultimately, I don't see the point in creating unique folders for each image (or record) but I don't have the full scope of the project in front of me to state otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make a CSV file containing ID and URL columns, say :

```
User204293,http://mywebsite.org/thepath/myavatar.png
```

You can use a variation of the following perl snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$DestRoot="/my/path/to/the/folders/";

open(IN,shift) or die;

while($line=<IN>){
  if ($line =~ m/^([^,]+),(http:\S+)/){
     my($id,$avatar)=($1,$2);
     mkdir($DestRoot.$id);
     chdir($DestRoot.$id);
     `wget $avatar`;
  }
}
close(IN);
```

and use it so

```
perl abovescript.pl myCSVfile.csv
```

The recommandations pointed by Marc B also apply!

Comment: could you tell me how i can make csv file from a mysql query result in php ?Furthermore , can the same be done using text file and DOS batching ?(text file holds username and image url )